# How can I state "everything is different from everything else" in First Order Logic?

Tags: first-order-logic, logic-translation

In my effort to express "*everything is different from everything else*", my first approach was to try "*There are exactly n distinct things*". The hope was that I could generalise the statement by adding a universal. For example:

$\forall x (x=x)$ identity

$(\exists x \exists y \exists z \neg(x=y) \land \neg(x=y) \land \neg(x=z) \land \neg(y=z))$ for ($n=3$).

Which seems to express difference using negated identity.

But, I could get no further.

Comment: $\forall x \forall y (x \ne y \to x \ne y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does "Everything is different from everything else'' mean. It could be saying: take anything thing and any other thing: then they are different things. Which is trivially true:

$$\forall x\forall y(x \neq y \to x \neq y)$$

Or something more substantial might be meant: given two distinct things there is some intrinsic property which distinguishes them (the contrapositive of a version of Leibniz's disputable principle of the identity of indiscernibles). But we'll need more than pure FOL to express this.